# Как можно указать в java диапазон натуральных чисел (0-6)?

Tags: java

Стоит задача написать программу, которая в зависимости от значения переменной, содержащей значение текущего часа выводит в терминал соответствующее этому часу сообщение. Задачу необходимо решить через Switch. В сутках 24 часа и писать 24 кейса будет не лучшим вариантом. Как можно в 1 case уместить значения от 0-6 , во 2й кейс 7 - 12 и тд. Пробовал через выражение inputNumber >=0 && inputNumber <=6, результат получается boolean и в кейс он не записывается.

Comment: Интересно, если бы такая возможность была, то как тогда Вы видите написание разных сообщений для 2го и 5того часа, если они попадают в один кейс от 0 до 6?

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались. Для диапазона 0-6 вывод в терминал одинаковый. Для 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 включительно. Если вводимое пользователем число попадает под этот кейс (условие) вывод будет 1 и тот же

Comment: Если использовать switch...case, то в java нет такой возможности, чтобы подставить диапазон. Поэтому придется 24 раза написать, разве что объединив несколько условий `case 1: case 2: case 3: ... System.out.println("1-6"); break; case 7: case 8: case 9: ... System.out.println("7-12"); break;`

Comment: Спасибо Alex, ценю ваш комментарий

Comment: Да не за что, максимум еще с Java 14 есть такая вещь https://stackoverflow.com/a/60135810/9033215, но это все равно далеко от того, что вы хотели бы получить.

Comment: Переходите на C#. В уютном дотнетике можно писать именно так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Я как Гарри Поттер, в лавке волшебных палочек. Не я выбрал Java, это Java выбрала меня :) Первый язык который пытаюсь осилить

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у Java разработчиков специфическое представление о развитии, если язык чего-то не сделал, они делают свою реализацию xD. Нет свойств, держите lombok. Нужны сахара, вот вам kotlin, который встраивается прямо в Java и позволяет писать `when (x) { in 1...6 -> println("1")  in 7...12 -> println("2") }`. Нужен функциональный стиль, держите scala.

Comment: А какие конкретно у вас диапазоны? Может, там по результату целочисленного деления на 6, например, можно делать проверку?

Comment: @КириллМалышев диапазоны как на циферблате часов. с 0 - 6 - ночь, 7-12 утро и тд. натуральные числа от 0-24 всего. Не вижу возможности тут делать проверки. Решил просто сделать так:
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число от 0 до 24");
        int inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (inputNumber) {
case 1 :
case 2 :
case 3 :
case 4 :
case 5 :
System.out.println("доброй ночи");
break;
case 6 :
case 7 :
case 8 :
case 9 :
case 10 :
case 11 :
System.out.println("Доброе утро");

Comment: Вам же уже дважды подсказали, что для данных диапазонов проще всего разделить число на 6, и будет всего 4 case

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
switch (inputNumber) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    ...
    case 6: 
        System.out.println("0-6");
        break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    ...
    case 12:
        System.out.println("7-12");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("дичь какая-то");
}
```

Всё равно 24 кейса, но действие-то можно написать только один раз для группы последовательно идущих кейсов.

Comment: То то и оно, что получается 24 кейса в любом случае. Видимо это просто требование задачи. В реальных условиях через if - else и уравнение решить эту задачу проще и красивее. 
А то я уже и приведение boolean к int пробовал и что только ни делал, всё без толку. 
Спасибо за не равнодушие!

Answer (score 2):

Если бы диапазоны часов были распределены равномерно по 6 часов:

```
[ 0,  6) -> [ 0.. 5], 
[ 6, 12) -> [ 6..11], 
[12, 18) -> [12..17], 
[18, 24) -> [18..23]
```

достаточно было бы обойтись четырьмя кейсами, разделив часы на ширину диапазона 6, как указано в комментариях и ответе Труфальдино (здесь и дальше используется синтаксис `switch`-*выражения*, доступного с Java 14):

```java
public static String timeRange(int h) {
    return switch(h / 6) {
        case 0 -> "Доброй ночи! 0 - 6";
        case 1 -> "Доброе утро! 6 - 12";
        case 2 -> "Добрый день! 13 - 18";
        case 3 -> "Добрый вечер! 18 - 24";
        default -> "Здравствуйте";
    };
}
```

Для неравномерного диапазона в "новом" синтаксисе `switch` можно перечислять значения через запятую (формально также будет 4 case):

```java
public static String timeRange(int h) {
    return switch(h) {
        case  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 6 -> "Доброй ночи! 0- 6"; // 7 значений 
        case  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12 -> "Доброе утро! 7 - 12";  // 6 значений
        case 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 -> "Добрый день! 13 - 18"; // 6 значений
        case 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 -> "Добрый вечер! 19 - 23";    // 5 значений
        default -> "Здравствуйте";
    };
}
```

---

Также для неравномерных диапазонов можно было бы создать `enum` с параметрами `from, to` и с методом для выбора соответствующего значения по входному значению hour:

```java
enum TimeOfDay {
    NIGHT(0, 6),
    MORNING(7, 12),
    DAY(13, 18),
    EVENING(19, 23);
    
    private final int from;
    private final int to;
    
    TimeOfDay(int f, int t) {
        this.from = f;
        this.to = t;
    }
    
    public static TimeOfDay byHour(int hour) {
        return Stream.of(TimeOfDay.values())
            .filter(td -> td.from <= hour && hour <= td.to)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Incorrect hour value, 0..23 expected, hour = " + hour
            ));
    }
}

public static String timeRange(int h) {
    return switch(TimeOfDay.byHour(h)) {
        case NIGHT -> "Доброй ночи! 0- 6";
        case MORNING -> "Доброе утро! 7 - 12";
        case DAY -> "Добрый день! 13 - 18";
        case EVENING -> "Добрый вечер! 19 - 23";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в Java не возможен такой вариант как `switch(true){...}`, и в `case` должны быть константы, не могут быть выражения, но можно пойти немного другим путем, тем более что `switch(true)` я бы предпочел обычный `if`.

Суть метода заключается в том что мы можем использовать условия как систему счисления т.е. к примеру бинарную ([4][2][1] - только один бит включен) , правда пример у меня на 10-ричной, но разницы *почти* нет.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int test(int n) {
        int case1 = (n >= 0 && n <= 6) ? 1: 0;
        int case2 = (n >= 7 && n <= 12) ? 2: 0;
        int case3 = (n >= 13 && n <= 18) ? 3: 0;

        switch(case1 + case2 + case3) {
          case 1:
            return 1;
          case 2:
            return 2;
          case 3:
            return 3;
          default:
            return 4;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i <24; i++ ){
        System.out.println("для " + i +  " кейс " + test(i));  
      }          
    }
}
```

Вариант с переменными `caseN` просто легче читается, по идее можно было   записать все в одно выражение, но его сложно было бы поддерживать. А используемый вариант позволяет хранить кейсы например в функциях.

Этот код может казаться избыточным в данном случае, но если бы речь шла о больших диапазонах или о более запутанных кейсах, возможно пересекающихся, т.е. когда несколько условий могут быть истинны(только бинарная система) то такой подход имеет смысл. А так же он имеет смысл если условия могут быть динамичны и задаваться через конфиг.

Comment: то есть, в этом примере мы прировняли через тернальный оператор булиан к инту?... класс! Признаться я даже об этом не подумал! Спасибо за идею!

Comment: да, я не раз использовал такой подход, он вполне оправдан, правда в приведенном примере совсем не понятно зачем switch если там не будет какого-то дополнительного кода))

Answer (score 1):

Не суди строго, но я не понял задачу.

```
  LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.now();
    int h= localTime.plusHours(6).getHour(); //каждые  шесть часов
    int t= h/6; //период между 6 часами
    switch (t) {
    case 1:
        System.out.print("utro :=" + h);
    break ;
    case 2:
    System.out.print("den :=" + h);
    break;
    case 3:
    System.out.print("vecher :=" + h);
    break ;
    default:
    System.out.print("noch :=" + h);
    break ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте такой `enum`:

```java
public enum FuzzyTime {
    NIGHT, MORNING, OTHER;

    public static FuzzyTime fromHour(int hour) {
        if (hour <= 6) {
            return NIGHT;
        } else if (hour <= 12) {
            return MORNING;
        } else {
            return OTHER;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь напишите `switch` так:

```java
int hour = ...;
switch (FuzzyTime.fromHour(hour)) {
    case NIGHT:
        System.out.println("Сейчас ночь");
        break;
    case MORNING:
        System.out.println("Сейчас утро");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Сейчас что-то другое");
        break;
}
```